# Determining the most popular MSC codes of new papers

Tags: journals, msc

How can I tell what are the most popular MSC codes of new papers (using arXiv and/or publications in MachSciNet indexed journals)? I would like to compare general areas (e.g. number theory vs dynamical systems) as well as specific codes like 11Y05, with date ranges like 1 year, 5 year, 10 year.

This question was answered in   [Quantitatively speaking, which subject area in mathematics is currently the most research active?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10801/quantitatively-speaking-which-subject-area-in-mathematics-is-currently-the-most) about 10 years ago, and I think an update is needed.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! May I suggest to change the title in order to reflect the content of the question more precisely? It seems debatable whether the number of publications is a good measure of "popularity" of a field. (And since MathOverflow is probably not the right place to discuss what is and what is not a good measure of popularity, I suggest to avoid this discussion by rephrasing the title.)

Comment: You can use "Citations" and then "Top 10" buttons in Mathscinet to estimate this. It gives you most cited papers in every MSN subject. Just compare how many times these top cited papers are cited. Compare between the subjects.

Comment: For example, in the subject 65 ten top papers have more than 1000 citations, while in the subject 31 a typical "top ten" paper is cited only about 200 times.

Comment: I edited the title in accordance with Jochen Glueck's suggestion.

Comment: "_People with subscription access_ can use "Citations" and then "Top 10" buttons in Mathscinet to estimate this." FTFY